# Joint Density & Expectations for 1/y

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

If X and Y have joint density function:

$f(x,y) = \frac1y$ for $0 < y < 1$ and $0 < x < y$; zero otherwise

Find:
a. $E[XY]$

b. $E[X]$

c. $E[Y]$

c. is fine. I found the marginal density of y (which ended up being 1) and then found $E[Y]$ to be 0.5.

b. is what is giving me trouble. When finding the marginal density of $x$, you end up with $\ln(y)$ where $y = 1$ and $y=0$. $\ln(1)$ is no problem, but $\ln$ is undefined at $y=0$. How can I calculate the marginal density of $f_X(x)$ so that I can then find $E[XY]$?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem you have with the density being infinite at one point is not a problem. PDFs can be infinite at points, they only need to (be nonnegative and) integrate to 1. (And note that already the joint PDF is infinite when y=0.)

Answer (score 2):

$$E(h(X,Y))=\iint h(x,y)f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_0^1\frac 1 y\int_0^y h(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\ldots$$

Comment: Note: the support of the pdf is $y\in(0, 1), x\in(0,y)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for the Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue $E[XY]=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} xy\frac{1}{y}dxdy=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} xdxdy=\frac{1}{6}$.

Likewise, $E[X]=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} \frac{x}{y}dxdy = \frac{1}{8}$

Comment: I reckon $E[X]=\frac{1}{4}$ if you work out the double integral..